# MEAN stack file structure & grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I am learning the MEAN stack by working on a personal project. At first, I used the combo of yeoman/grunt/bower, but I wasn't happy with the file structure that the yeoman generators had, so now I just have a manually configured grunt and node.js in my project.

As I prototype my app, I keep questioning whether my file structure is good or not. I've done a lot of research, but I can't find a better way of organizing my public/ folder.

This is what my project structure looks like:

- api/

  - models/ *(mongodb models here)*
  - db.js *(express connection settings here)*
  - routes.js *(express routes here)*
- node_modules/ *(npm modules here)*
- **public/**

  - css/ *(css files here)*
  - img/ *(images here)*
  - js/

    - views/ *(angular views here)*
    - app.js
  - index.html
- **src/**

  - css/ *(css files here)*
  - img/ *(images here)*
  - js/

    - controllers/ *(angular controllers here)*
    - directives/ *(angular directives here)*
    - views/ *(angular views here)*
  - index.html
- gruntfile.js
- server.js

I do all my coding in src/. Grunt copies all html files (index.html and js/views/), css and images over to public, and uglifies all my angular js files into public/js/app.js.

Does this sound like a good idea? I am trying to keep my app extremely modular, while minimizing it for production. Is there a better/cleaner way to deal with the angular js/view files?

Thanks!

Comment: It's too bad this question is closed. I can't find any good documentation on how folder structure is supposed to work with pre/post-processing and the MEAN stack. I'm not a huge fan of duplicating everything from a `src` folder to `public` but, that's the solution I'm working with right now too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out these repos for some ideas.

- [unbox](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox) is a project I maintain that helps me quickly set up a MEAN stack type of architecture
- [bevacqua.io](https://github.com/bevacqua/io) is my personal website, built on top of unbox
- [brut](https://github.com/bevacqua/brut) is another example on top of unbox, but it uses Angular and pre-compiles the templates

Talking directory structure, I do something similar to your approach.

```
bin/ (built, static, site here)
src/
  statics/
    css/
    js/
    img/
  views/
```

Basically I treat everything that composes the website as "source", and I compiled everything as needed, putting it into `bin`, and serve the application from there.